# How to install composer dependencies when the root folder of the Google App Engine project is outside the composer.json directory?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, composer-php

I'm using Google App engine to deploy a PHP project.
I'm using the following file structure.

```sh
public/project_files_here_composer.json_here_too
private/some_private_files
app.yaml
```

In app.yaml I set the public folder to be the web root directory that contains the index.php .
When I deploy this with `google app deploy` , my composer dependencies are not installed.

How to tell Google App Engine to install my dependencies inside the the `public/` folder (using the composer.json in the public folder) ?

Comment: Why exactly are your dependencies not installed? What have you tried to fix that?

Comment: I needed to run gcloud app install on the outer directory so that it copies both my public and private folder to the production environment, but my composer.json file is inside the public folder. So the problem is that Google app engine is not runing  composer install when I try to deploy the app, and I can't move composer.json outside the public directory. So how to let Google app engine cd to public folder and then run composer install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been searching on the documentation for the [`gcloud app deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) operation and the [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref) file and I didn't manage to find any reference to what you intend to do. Trying to reproduce your scenario, what I did was to create a soft link in the app's root directory that pointed to the composer file in another folder, but it didn't work.

What did work was creating a hard link in the app's root folder with the following command:

```
ln public/composer.json composer.json
```

Regardless, when I made the `gcloud app deploy` command, it said that it was uploading 0 files (which is kinda true), but when I looked on the source from the Console, the file was there and the dependencies were installed, so it works.

If you don't want to create a hard link, you should just create a script that copies the file, deploys and removes it. Something in the lines of:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cp public/composer.json .
gcloud app deploy
rm composer.json
```

If none of these works for you, you should just move the composer.json to the app's root directory.